# Regex in Visual Studio Code Search/Replace to change urls with any structure

Tags: html, regex, visual-studio-code, regex-greedy

I am looking to replace all old CDN URLs with my new site URL. The CDN URLs vary in length and structure and sometimes the CDN prefix can be slightly different too.

I have been using the following, but these also changes some other CDN URLs such as FontAwesome and others that I don't want. So just need something a bit more specific

```
(https?://)(.*?)(/.*)
```

**URLS TO CAPTURE**

```
https://lirp-cdn.multiscreensite.com/624dfs85te/dms3rep/multi/opt/logo-400w.jpg
https://lirp-cdn.multiscreensite.com/624dfs85te/dms3rep/multi/opt/home04-96006935-1920w.jpg
https://irp-cdn.multiscreensite.com/624dfs85te/dms3rep/multi/home02.jpg
```

**DESIRED RESULT**

```
https://mywebsite.com/logo-400w.jpg
https://mywebsite.com/home04-96006935-1920w.jpg
https://mywebsite.com/home02.jpg
```

Comment: is `https://irp-cdn.multiscreensite.com` a typo? no `l`

Comment: No, it seems to use that as well. I need the filename retaining, so not a full capture of the url.

Comment: I used a `?` in the answer to deal with this

Comment: You should also show the url forms you have that you don't want matched.

Answer (score 1):

Incorporate the domain of the CDN

You must remove the `?` from the `*?` because you want all the directories in group 2, only the last `/` in group 3.

```
(https?://)(l?irp-cdn.multiscreensite.com.*)(/.*)
```

Comment: This still seems to capture the entire url including the filename and extension, which actually needs excluding. This is so the new url can be inserted from the "replace" box in front of the image url to reflect the new domain server url.

Comment: @sigur7 see https://regex101.com/r/JsnPEs/1 it seems to work

Comment: @Mark The escapes are only needed in regex101

Comment: I wonder if in reality there need to be any capture groups at all - given the likely input.  See https://regex101.com/r/JsnPEs/4

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
(https?://)l?irp-cdn\.multiscreensite\.com(?:/.*)?(/.*)
```

Replace with:

```
$1mywebsite.com$2
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/HgZQn9/2)

EXPLANATION:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    http                     'http'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    s?                       's' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ://                      '://'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  l?                       'l' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  irp-cdn                  'irp-cdn'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  multiscreensite          'multiscreensite'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  com                      'com'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
```

Comment: From the question: `(https?://)(.*?)(/.*)` matches "some other CDN URLs such as FontAwesome and others that I don't want".